# Library in the Android source tree is not getting built

Tags: android, build, makefile, android-source, hal

Specifically, I'm trying to build the **sensors.hammerhead.so**, which is under *device/lge/hammerhead/libsensors/*
I have the **4.4.2_r1** branch downloaded and compiled. 
But this module is not being built (can't find it under *out/target/product/hammerhead/system/lib/hw* or *system/vendor/lib/hw*)
I tried using `mmm device/lge/hammerhead/libsensors` but I get:

> make: Nothing to be done for `all_modules'.

Other modules such as lights.hammerhead.so (*device/lge/hammerhead/liblight/*) or sensors.default.so (*hardware/akm/AKM8975_FS/libsensors/*) work fine with `mmm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in device/lge/hammerhead/libsensors/Android.mk you'll see that the entire contents of the file is excluded with a `ifeq (0,1)` conditional:

```
ifeq (0,1)
ifneq ($(TARGET_BUILD_PDK), true)
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
...
endif
endif
```

Using `git blame` we can find that this conditional was added in commit 4e858dde. I have no idea *why* the module is disabled, but you can reenable it by reverting said commit (`git revert 4e858dde`). Whether this will result in something that actually works is another matter. You might find additional clues by walking through the history of the git. This particular sensor has gone through a long series for enable-disable-enable-disable commits.

Comment: Ohh I don't know how I missed that! Thanks so much and also for the tips using git. Btw, I also noticed that "sensors.hammerhead" is not included in `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in _device/lge/hammerhead/device.mk_, does that matter?

Comment: The inclusion or exclusion of a module in PRODUCT_PACKAGES normally won't affect whether the module is built, but obviously comes into play when considering what gets installed.